# nginx reverse proxy serving wrong site

Tags: nginx, debian, proxy

I have nginx running on Debian 12 as reverse proxy -with SSL termination- for several sites.
Recently noticed that I'm not able to add more hosts anymore due to this strange behaviour.
Have default site enabled but, systematically, when I point the browser to sub-xx.domain.com got redirected to a.domain.com. However, every site from a to w is working as expected.
If the request is HTTP browser warns about site insecurity and got redirected to d.domain.com. When you explicitly request HTTPS got redirected to a.domain.com as mentioned.
Logs from xx.domain.com has no trace and, just if the request is HTTPS, the ones from a.domain.com has this

```
192.168.9.1 - - [19/Jan/2024:16:55:04 -0300] "GET /img/logo.gif HTTP/2.0" 200 3418 "https://xx.domain.com/css/login>
```

**xx.conf**

```
pstream xx {
   server 192.168.8.86;
   keepalive 32;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.domain.com;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/location-letsencrypt.conf;

#    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

#}

#server {
#    listen 443 ssl http2;

#    server_name test.xx.domain.com;
    
#    include /etc/nginx/snippets/location-letsencrypt.conf;
#    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xx.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
       include /etc/nginx/snippets/proxy.conf;

       proxy_pass http://test_xx/;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/xx.domain.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/xx.domain.com/error.log;

}
```

**yy.conf**

```
upstream yy {
   server 192.168.8.81;
   keepalive 32;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yy.domain.com;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/location-letsencrypt.conf;

#    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

#}

#server {
#    listen 443 ssl http2;

#    server_name yy.domain.com;
    
#    include /etc/nginx/snippets/location-letsencrypt.conf;
#    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

#    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yy.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yy.domain.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
       proxy_pass_request_headers   on;
       proxy_pass http://yy/;
  }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/yy.domain.com/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/yy.domain.com/error.log;

}
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 10240;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # To avoid error 413
    client_max_body_size 192M;


    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] 
                             "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent 
                             "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent"
                             "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access-special.log combined;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**location-letsencrypt.conf**

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow all;
    default_type "text/plain";
    root /var/www/le_root;
}

location = /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the xx.conf file, the proxy_pass is pointing to test_xx instead of xx as the upstream is declared.

Comment: Can you do an `curl -i -L sub-xx.domain.com`. This will follow redirects and show headers for each request. Look for the Location header in the response to see if there's a redirection, and check for any X-Forwarded-For or Via headers to indicate proxying.

Comment: @MarcoZink my bad when masking real data

Comment: @Turdie this is what I get

`
# curl -i -L sub-xx.domain.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 22 Jan 2024 13:23:05 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.58
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=3nqsvchgnl72v13lhb639c8r4k; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
`

Such response is from an Apache hosting an in-house app, and is not the server response I'm looking for.